# Hebrews 10:25 - Is this about meeting daily?

Tags: hebrews

Hebrews 10:25 
"Not forsaking the assembling of ourselves together, as is the manner of some, but exhorting one another, and so much the more as you see the Day approaching."  NKJV

Is the writer actually arguing for a return to Acts 2...  Daily meeting together, breaking bread, going over the word etc?

He is not arguing that they need to meet together 1x a week, but OFTEN.

Arguments for this approach:
The writer wrote a book to a group of people... hence they were already meeting.
As he lists the value of meeting together, he never includes preaching, worship etc.  Corporate things.  Hebrews 10 includes personal benefits - exhorting one another, provoking one another etc.

Arguments against this approach:
The preponderance of commentaries that say this is all about getting Christians that are not coming to church, to start coming to church.
The word includes "synagogue."  So that seems to imply a large religious gathering and not smaller house to house meetings.

Conclusion: No matter what line you take, Christians must meet together.  That is not in doubt.  I just wonder if it is fair to lift up the value of meeting with other Christians often, outside of the walls of a building...

I would appreciate any insights!!

Comment: Could you explain please how that word "includes" synagogues. (Daily's wonderful, but I can't imagine Paul, I believe, is specifying it)

Comment: The word, "often" is NOT in the Greek text of English that you quote.  To what are you alluding?

Comment: The frequency of meeting is NOT stated so this question cannot be answered.  Formal buildings for Christian meeting only began to appear in the 4th century.  History records that meetings were either held in people's homes or isolated places where local authorities frowned on Christians.

Comment: If the opposite to 'forsaking assembling' is 'exhorting one another' then Hebrews 3:13 is relevant : Take heed, brethren, lest there be in any of you an evil heart of unbelief, in departing from the living God. 13 _But exhort one another daily_, while it is called To day; lest any of you be hardened through the deceitfulness of sin. To exhort daily, one must meet daily.

Answer (score 1):

The BLB version gives a very literal rendering of the Greek of Heb 10:25:

> not forsaking the assembling together of ourselves as is the custom
> with some, but encouraging one another, and so much more as you see
> the Day drawing near.

Note that there is no mention or even hint of frequency of assembling together.  He does not say it is daily, weekly monthly or yearly - it is simply not mentioned.  What IS said is the custom of meeting together, ie, the habit of doing so.

All the author is saying is - do not break the habit of regular meetings.  Nothing more or less.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that since the text does not specify the "place" of assembly, this would be immaterial. Whether the place of meeting is the synagogue, the temple, a private dwelling (which was the norm until the third century), or church buildings (which began to appear in the third century) would seem quite beside the point.

The Hebrew writer is informing us that (regardless of the location), unfaithfulness to the assembly = sin. Our personal habits of honoring the assembly are a barometer for our spiritual condition. This is a reflection of one's attitude toward God and toward one another.

1. Forsaking the assembly can become a habit. Complacency builds from a tendency to rationalize the behavior.

   a. Assembly forsaken in favor of other things

   b. Assembly forsaken to avoid:

   - Uncomfortable relationships with other members, the preacher, a certain teacher or the elders, or any other reason one may use as a rationalization to justify avoiding the assembly.
   - Being confronted for sin in their lives.
2. Forsaking the assembly is a decision of the will and the Hebrew writer says this behavior is an insult to the Spirit of grace.
3. It is regarded by the text as a rejection of the covenant between you and God. This sets aside one's covenant with God in favor of personal comfort and other interests.

a. This person has *“trampled underfoot the Son of God.”*

b. It regards as unclean the blood of Christ - The proverbial hog slaughtered on the altar.

In short, the behavior is inexcusable and not without consequences.

Since the text itself does not address in any way the frequency of assembling, we are forced to rely upon other texts of scripture to determine how often the Church is commanded to come together. Historically, it was not uncommon for the Church to meet daily, especially in times of great troubles.

Comment: You seem not to have addressed the question - Is this about meeting _daily_ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hebrews 10:25 - Is this about meeting daily?**

Meeting at least once a week, and possibly two.

Hebrews 10:24-25 (NKJV)

24 "And let us consider one another in order to stir up love and good works, 25 not forsaking the assembling of ourselves together, as is the manner of some, but exhorting one another, and so much the more as you see the Day approaching."

The words of Paul above show that God wants people to gather together as an organized congregation for worship, to gain spiritual benefits. This is emphasized with the annual Passover observances:(Numbers 9:9-14)

Numbers 9:13 NKJV

> 13" But the man who is clean and is not on a journey, and ceases to
>   keep the Passover, th**at same person shall be cut off from among his
>   people, because he did not bring the offering of the Lord at its
>   appointed time; that man shall bear his sin."**

When King Hezekiah called inhabitants of Judah and Israel to Jerusalem for a Passover celebration, his message was, in part:

2 Chronicles 30:6-9 (NKJV)

> 6 "Then the runners went throughout all Israel and Judah with the
>   letters from the king and his leaders, and spoke according to the
>   command of the king: “Children of Israel, return to the Lord God of
>   Abraham, Isaac, and Israel; then He will return to the remnant of you
>   who have escaped from the hand of the kings of Assyria. 7 And do not
>   be like your fathers and your brethren, who trespassed against the
>   Lord God of their fathers, so that He gave them up to desolation, as
>   you see."
>
> 8 "Now do not be stiff-necked,[a] as your fathers were, but yield
>   yourselves to the Lord; and enter His sanctuary, which He has
>   sanctified forever, and serve the Lord your God, that the fierceness
>   of His wrath may turn away from you. 9 For if you return to the Lord,
>   your brethren and your children will be treated with compassion by
>   those who lead them captive, so that they may come back to this land;
>   for the Lord your God is gracious and merciful, and will not turn His
>   face from you if you return to Him.”

Although such festivals are not a Christion requirement,  **willful failure to attend would certainly have indicated a forsaking of God.** Hence Paul fittingly urged Christians not to abandon regular assemblies of God's people:  "25 not forsaking the assembling of ourselves together, as is the manner of some, but exhorting one another, and so much the more as you see the Day approaching."(Heb 10:25 NKJV)

Comment: Can you explain why you're associating this passage from Hebrews with the Passover? Also, where did "meeting at least once a week, and possibly two" come from? I can't find anything in the passages you've quoted that would support this.